# Sending message in JSQMessagesController

Tags: ios, swift, xmpp, xmppframework, jsqmessagesviewcontroller

I want to send my message and I know that it sends via

```
override func didPressSendButton(button: UIButton!, withMessageText text: String!, senderId: String!, senderDisplayName: String!, date: NSDate!) {
    let message = JSQMessage(senderId: "alizade@my.co", senderDisplayName: "The Flash", date: NSDate(), text: text)

// SENDING CODE HERE
}
```

this function, but I do not know how to send it on press on the send button.

I searched and found this example:

```
OneMessage.sendMessage(text, to: recipient.jidStr, completionHandler: { (stream, message) -> Void in
    JSQSystemSoundPlayer.jsq_playMessageSentSound()
        self.finishSendingMessageAnimated(true)
    })
```

but I do not have .sendMessage method in my case. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

sendMessage is just a function that was written outside of the the framework itself and I'm guessing is found in a subclass of JSQMessagesViewController. You'll still want to fire off whatever logic you'll run inside of didPressSendButton.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using an array for the datasource of JSQMessagesViewController, just add the message (of type JSQMessage) to the array and call `self.finishSendingMessageAnimated(true)` to trigger the refresh and animation.

If you're using core data, you'll need to store the message in your database and depend on NSFetchedResultsController to trigger the update in `controllerDidChangeContent` or the other callback methods.

Since you're using XMPPFramework, you might also want to compose the message xml element and send it using the XMPPStream.

Hope that helps!